Flower bend difficulty
I have a simple flower on a flat plane. I want to bend the flower along the z axis, so it folds to the inside but limited to a certain point (like the image). The problem is, I want this limit to have a smoother falloff. I got the bend correct, the bottom part should bend more than the “leave” part (see nodes) but the border needs to be not that abrupt. If that makes sense. Maybe this is a simple solution but I can’t get it to work. So any info could help!


you don't have to, but providing a blend file will always attract more (lazy like me) people because we don't have to rebuild everything manually.

That a good point, did not think about that. Next time I will add the file!!

The Simple Deform: Bend modifier works by converting flat to polar coordinates in such a way that the loop at one (here: $y$) coordinate equal to zero will keep its length (here the length is $2 = πr$ therefore $r = {2 \over π} = 0.636619772367581...$)

And as you can see the distance to the $x$ axis adds to the radius, causing stretching.


For the leaf it will look like this:


